# Error during form generation: Could not load type "CustomType"

Tags: symfony, symfony3.x

There is an error during execute the `createForm` method.

`InvalidArgumentException: Could not load type "ArticleType"`

My symfony version is `3.3.*`.

I tried to execute the `createForm` method with `Article::class` instead of `ArticleType::class`.

Here is my code, where is the problem?

**ArticleController.php**

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $article = new Article();

    $form = $this->createForm(ArticleType::class, $article);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        // ...
    }

    return $this->render('admin/article/create.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

**ArticleType.php**

```
class ArticleType extends AbstractType
{
    private $categoryService;
    private $tagService;

    public function __construct(CategoryService $categoryService, TagService $tagService)
    {
        $this->categoryService = $categoryService;
        $this->tagService = $tagService;
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */.
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => 'CMS\Bundle\ContentBundle\Entity\Article'
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Resources/config/services.yml** (included in app/config/services.yml)

```
services:
  CMS\Bundle\ContentBundle\Form\ArticleType:
    arguments: ['@cms.core.service.category', '@cms.core.service.tag']
    tags: [form.type]
```

.

Comment: Your tags is wrong, I think you even do not need it in symfony 3.3 but you should use it like   `tags:
        - { name: form.type }`

Comment: @kunicmarko20 I tried like that but the error still exists. :( Thank you.

Comment: @kunicmarko20 - Just for info, starting in 3.3 there is indeed an alternate and simplified approach to specifying tags when all you need is a name.  In fact, the tag is not even needed anymore at all since anything derived from AbstractType is automatically tagged with form.type.  This is almost certainly a namespace issue.

Comment: @Cerad I thought so as I did not register any of my form types in current 3.3 project :) , ty for info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your custom form class can't be found in the current namespace(s). Try adding `use CMS\Bundle\ContentBundle\Form\ArticleType;` (or something similar) to your controller.